Using map merging (<<) in an externally included yml file in Gitlab CI/CD
The main gitlab CI configuration file looks like this:
.gitlab-ci.yml -
include:
 - 'test.yml' 

stages:
  - build
  - dev

.template: &deploy
  dependencies:
    - build

.template: &build
  image: node:18.20.0
  stage: build
  script:
    - uname -a
    - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}
    - npm cache clean --force
    - npm install
    - ...

build:
  <<: *build

Now, in the included file test.yml -
job-1:
  <<: *deploy
  stage: dev
  environment:
    name: dev
  script:
    - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}
    - ...
  only:
    - master
  when: manual

When I push this file on Gitlab, pipelines are not created and I see this error message -

Unable to create pipeline test.yml: content does not have a valid YAML syntax

However when I remove <<: *deploy from job-1 pipeline is created and works fine.
How can I use << in an included file?

In pipeline editor, you can view your complete gitlab-ci.yml for debugging, can you show him


content does not have a valid YAML syntax

Could it be that the file defines .template: twice? They have different aliases, but I think the names have to be different too.

I also tried different aliases like .deploy and .build. Even this didn't work.
